# Unit for BitmapFactory.Options.outHeight/outWidth

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

The document doesn't say clearly what the unit `outHeight` and `outWidth` is.

> The resulting height of the bitmap, set independent of the state of
>   inJustDecodeBounds. However, if there is an error trying to decode,
>   outHeight will be set to -1.

Is it measured in dp, pixel or inch?

Answer (score 3):

Pixels. Bitmap sizes are measured in pixels.